# Did medical droids or Darth Sidious keep Vader from death?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, darth-sidious, revenge-of-the-sith

After Anakin received mortal wounds on Mustafar, he was rescued, healed, and augmented into the incarnation of Darth Vader we all recognize.

Earlier in Episode III, Palpatine mentioned that Darth Plagueis's apprentice (Darth Sidious) learned everything from his master, implying also that he could keep people from dying.

Do we have any indication that this wasn't a bluff? If not a bluff, did Sidious use this power to keep Vader alive while the medical droids did their work? Or was it solely the work of the droids (or maybe medical personnel)?

Comment: Scutters. I think it was scutters.

Comment: The answer to this question is YES

Comment: @CHEESE Aaaaargh!

Comment: @CreationEdge Funny, that's exactly what my sister says when I do that.

Comment: @CreationEdge On a more serious note, it could not be YES.  Maybe it was Anikin's sensitivity to the Force that saved him?

Comment: If SIdious could fix medical problems, the first thing he would fix is his own scarred and twisted face.  When Jabba the Hutt can pull more women than you, it's definitely Nip 'n Tuck time.

Comment: @KyleJones Technically, Palpatine told Anakin that Plagueis couldn't do it to himself, that's how he died!

Comment: I'm thinking a lot of gauze was involved, as well.

Comment: You underestimate the power of the dark side.

Comment: @thegreatjedi No, I'm just not a fan of cookies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We know from the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)) that Sidious did indeed use his Force powers (presumably those described earlier in the film) to keep Vader alive while the medical pod was being brought from the shuttle. Beyond that point, we know from other sources that Star Wars medical science is sufficiently advanced that pretty much anyone who gets to a dedicated medical facility will survive [almost any level of injury](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/74192/20774).

> Relief swept his doubts away. “Get a medical capsule immediately,”
>   Darth Sidious commanded, and clones ran off to do his bidding. **Leaning
>   down, he placed a hand on Darth Vader’s forehead, using the dark side
>   to keep him alive.**

and

> **The medical capsule kept Darth Vader alive during the trip to
>   Coruscant.**

Comment: Like you said, [almost any level of injury](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76856/what-did-padm%C3%A9-die-of).

Comment: @Ellesedil - Everything save a broken heart.

Comment: I was actually hoping the novel would cover this.